# RECYCLE VIEW onBindFucntion not working as I am following and learnign through a tuitorial

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

So i have been following this tuitorial and for soem reason I can not import my text from xml to kotlin file.
I have tried diffrent things but it still wont work.

I did add id 'kotlin-android-extensions' to my gradle:module:app but still wot go though.

Here is my code

todoAdapter.kt
`

```
package com.example.todo

import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class todoAdapter(
    private val todos : MutableList<Todo>
):RecyclerView.Adapter<todoAdapter.TodoViewHolder>() {

    class TodoViewHolder(itemView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): TodoViewHolder {
        val view =  LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_todo,parent,false);
        return TodoViewHolder(view);
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: TodoViewHolder, position: Int) {
           val curTodo =  todos[position]

           holder.itemView.tv (this bracket is not included in the code, the reason i onyl wrote tv is that if i wrote full it would be a red text and not get thr refrence)


    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size;
    }
}
```

`

item_todo.xml

`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:paddingStart="14dp"
    android:paddingEnd="14dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTodoTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/tvCheckboxTodo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`

I have tried using the apply but that funciton too doesnt seem to work , I just wanna know where I am doing htinsg wrong. Please expalin begnier level as I am still lenring

Comment: `I can not import my text from xml to kotlin file` what do you mean by this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to do this:

```
class TodoViewHolder(itemView:View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val tvTodoTitle: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTodoTitle)
    val tvCheckboxTodo: Checkbox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvCheckboxTodo)
}
```

Then in your `onBindViewHolder` you can do

```
holder.tvTodoTitle.text = "Whatever you want"
```

Answer (score 0):

You must create the reference first then you can call it later. You can create `tvTodoTitle` in the body of class `TodoViewHolder` by the following code:

> TextView tvTodoTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTodoTitle);

then in `onBindViewHolder` you can call the `tvTodoTitle` reference:

> holder.itemView.tvTodoTitle ...